# Get list of cities for Belgium via Wikidata

Tags: php, wikidata-api

I'm a fairly new programmer and would like to get the cities of Belgian via Wikidata. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find an endpoint of how to get it. The documentation URL is https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6984567?

Comment: It seems to me it would be [this](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities) (examples are at the bottom). The entity id is in the url you included in your question (`Q6984567`).

Comment: Thanks. But I still do not see the endpoint to get all the Belgian cities as Belgium has Q31 as ID 

Comment: Try with [list of cities in Belgium](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q188815) directly?